# Question about semi-twin primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Has anyone ever studied the following numbers? I came up with the name *semi-twin primes* as I could not find any reference on this topic. These are prime numbers $p$ such that $p+1 = 2q$, with $q$ being a prime. The list starts with $p= 3, 5, 13, 37, 61, 73$ and so on. I searched Google for $3, 5, 13, 37, 61, 73$ but didn't find anything.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A005383 (OEIS is the first place to search for a sequence).

Comment: @Ethan: Thanks! Very useful.

Comment: similar but different:  $q$ is a [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) if $2q \color{red}+ 1$ is also prime; cf. also [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime)

Comment: P be any prime > 2 , P±1 would have gaps of multiples of 2 , what specific we can do with your semi twins?

Comment: cunningham chain of second kind if repeated.

Comment: According to the generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture, infinite many such pairs exist, but as one would expect it is open whether this is actually the case.

Comment: @EthanBolker I agree , but with some restrictions. Occasionally, OEIS contains typos because apparently the sequences are not doublechecked. Also, I hate sites that beg for donations. A third negative aspect : Enzo Creti ( a user on this site ) wanted to delete an entry (I do not remember why). He said that he was not allowed to do that.

Comment: @VincentGranville In this case, you do not need OEIS. A simple pari/gp program gives you the solutions upto a quite high limit very fast. Even examples with several hundred digits could easily be found this way.

Comment: @Peter Yes, you can find many more terms - but OEIS may tell you whether anyone else has looked at your particular sequence.